# Como corrigir problema de CSS com letter-spacing e texto alinhado a direita?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Eu e tenho uma situação na qual tenho um container com duas linhas de texto dentro alinhadas a direita. Só que uma das linhas está com a propriedade `letter-spacing: 15px;` mara aumentar o espaçamento entre os caracteres.

O problema é que o `letter-spacing` aumenta o espaço apenas para a direita, dessa forma o texto não fica alinhado corretamente no direita ficando um espaço vazio a direita entre o final do texto e o container.

Eu sei que colocando um `margin-right` negativo no mesmo valor de `letter-spacing` eu corrigi isso. Só que eu tenho texto de vário tamanhos com `letter-spacing` de vários tamanhos e não quero ter que ficar repetindo sempre um `margin-right` para cada `letter` diferente.

**Exite alguma forma de automatizar isso sem precisar ficar sempre repetindo o valor negativo no `margin-right`?**

**Existe alguma forma de usar `CSS Variables` para automatizar isso? Tipo se o meu `letter-spacing` for `X` tem como automaticamente passar esse valor para o meu `margin-right`?**

```css
p + p {
    letter-spacing: 15px;
}
p {
  color: orangered;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.box {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Titlem</p>
  <p>taglinem</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se declarar o valor como uma variável e utilizar a funcão calc, para invertê-lo no `margin-right`, você consegue contornar o problema.

```css
p + p {
    --espaco : 15px;
    letter-spacing: var(--espaco);
    margin-right: calc(var(--espaco) * -1);
}
p {
  color: orangered;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.box {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Titlem</p>
  <p>taglinem</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Cara acho que é por ai mesmo. Como pretendo usar em vários elementos com valores diferentes eu preferi criar uma classe só como o letter e a margin, e uma var com valor 0 no :root, ai eu só faço o override do valor na classe do elemento que tb tiver o letter... Pra ficar mais claro https://codepen.io/hugocsl/pen/wQqpRg Valeu a dica me ajudou!

Comment: Boa, acabei perceber outro detalhe, na `.box` seria necessário um `overflow-x : hidden`. Seleciona o o texto com o `letter-spacing` pra você ver.

Comment: Realmente seria prudente usar o overflow!